# Flyway multi database migration using API

Tags: flyway

I am using flyway-api for migrations and now I need to separate mysql and derby migrations.
I have now migrations under db.migrations.
How can I now separate migrations for mysql, derby? I need separate scripts for both.

Answer (score 0):

See the Flyway FAQ for the answer: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq.html#db-specific-sql